# HTML is being rendered as literal string using RazorEngine. How can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to generate a HTML document with RazorEngine (http://razorengine.codeplex.com/). Everything is *mostly* working, but the problem I have now is some of the HTML is being rendered correctly, and HTML that I have nested in that is being rendered as literal HTML, so rather than the browser displaying the tables & divs as expected, it's displaying e.g.

```
 "<table></table><div></div>"
```

I kick off this process by calling the following:

```
string completeHTML = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse("InstallationTemplate.cshtml", new { Data = viewModels });
```

The `completeHTML` is then written to a file.

"InstallationTemplate.cshtml" is defined as:

```
@{
    var installationReport = new InstallationReport(Model.Data);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>        
        <div>
            <!-- I would expect this to write the rendered HTML
                 in place of "@installationReport.DigiChannels()" -->
            @installationReport.DigiChannels()    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where `InstallationReport` and `DigiChannels` are defined as follows:

```
public static class InstallationReportExtensions
{
    public static string DigiChannels(this InstallationReport installationReport)
    {
        return installationReport.GetDigiChannelsHtml();
    }
}

public class InstallationReport
{
    public string GetDigiChannelsHtml()
    {
        // the following renders the template correctly
        string renderedHtml = RazorReport.GetHtml("DigiChannels.cshtml", GetDigiChannelData());
        return renderedHtml;
    }
}

public static string GetHtml(string templateName, object data)
{
    var templateString = GetTemplateString(templateName);

    return RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(templateString, data);
}
```

After `GetDigiChannelsHtml()` runs and returns `renderedHtml`, the line of execution returns to `TemplateBase.cs` into the method `ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext context)`, which is defined as:

```
    string ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder)) 
        {
            _context.CurrentWriter = writer;

            Execute(); // this is where my stuff gets called

            _context.CurrentWriter = null;
        }

        if (Layout != null)
        {
            // Get the layout template.
            var layout = ResolveLayout(Layout);

            // Push the current body instance onto the stack for later execution.
            var body = new TemplateWriter(tw => tw.Write(builder.ToString()));
            context.PushBody(body);

            return layout.Run(context);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

When I inspect `builder.ToString()`, I can see it contains proper HTML for the `InstallationTemplate.cshtml` stuff, and escaped HTML for the `DigiChannels.cshtml` stuff. For example:

[image]

How can I get `@installationReport.DigiChannels()` to include the correct HTML instead of the escaped HTML that it's currently doing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@Raw(installationReport.DigiChannels())
```

Edit : I could use it in following way (MVC3)

```
@Html.Raw(installationReport.DigiChannels())
```

Comment: Nope, I didn't try that (didn't even know!). It worked perfectly. Thanks. I have to wait a few mins before I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks, yes it pretty much does the same thing as Html.Raw (when using razor with ASP.NET MVC)

Answer (score 5):

The alternative to `@Raw` is to change your API to return [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx)s in appropriate places

> Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again.

The default razor behaviour is to encode `string`s.